# Capture screen without spaces?

Tags: swift

I have a few png's on a view in which I capture to an image :

```
let rect: CGRect = self.frame
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, false, 0.0);
        let context: CGContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
        self.layer.render(in: context)
        let img: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

Problem is, that I want to get a final png size as the size of the content on the view, and **not as a constant rect size** `rect.size` .

So if the lower content start at 50px and max content ends at 200px, the height of my new png will be 150.

Comment: did you manage to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

You should iterate through your views to detect the boundaries of your *content*.

You can **calculate the frame manually**:

```
var minX = view.frame.origin.x + view.frame.size.width
var minY = view.frame.origin.y + view.frame.size.height
var maxX = 0
var maxY = 0

for subview in self.subviews {
    minX = min(minX, subview.frame.origin.x)
    minY = min(minY, subview.frame.origin.y)
    maxX = max(maxX, subview.frame.origin.x + subview.frame.size.width)
    maxY = max(maxY, subview.frame.origin.y + subview.frame.size.height)
}

var newPngRect = CGRect(x: minX, y: minY, width: maxX-minX, height: maxY-minY)

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newPngRect!, false, 0.0)
```

Or **determine the [union](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgrect/1455837-union) of your subviews**:

```
var newPngRect = CGRect.zero
for subview in subviews {
    baseRect = baseRect.union(subview.frame)
}

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newPngRect, false, 0.0)
```

Consider that `self.subviews` could be replaced for `yourContentView.subviews` in case its needed.

Comment: I think this is wrong for some cases. Say there's 1 subview, located at (1, 1) with a width of 1 and height of 1. This gives a minX of 0, minY of 0, and width/height of 1. The safer/less manual solution would be to wrap all the views you care about screenshotting within 1 view and call `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions` on its rect.

Comment: True @Connor, I've change the answer to consider the single subview case

Comment: That's not the only problem. Same bug will happen if you add another subview at (2, 2). The logic for `minX` and `minY` are wrong.

Comment: Ofc, because the initial value should be bigger than the origin of the screen. Now it should work

Answer (score 0):

Create a single view that contains all of the subviews for which you want to screenshot (a `containerView`).

Use auto layout to layout all of its subviews however you want.

When you're ready to screenshot the view, use:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(containerView.frame.size, false, 0.0);
let context: CGContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
containerView.layer.render(in: context)
let img: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

Comment: Thanks, but what is this  ? you copy my code ? this is what I did, it will create spaces.

Comment: It is not the same as your code. I explained what to do differently.